# Can I group graphite results by regex?

Tags: python, graphite

I've been using graphite for some time now in order to power our backend pythonic program. As part of my usage of it, I need to sum (using sumSeries) different metrics using wildcards.

Thing is, I need to group them according to a pattern; say I have the following range of metric names:

`group.*.item.*`

I need to sum the values of all items, for a given group (meaning: `group.1.item.*`, `group.2.item.*`, etc)

Unfortunately, I do not know in advance the set of existing group values, and so what I do right now is that I query `metrics/index.json`, parse the list, and generated the desired query (manually creating `sumSeries(group.NUMBER.item.*)` for every NUMBER I find in the metrics index).

I was wondering if there was a way to have graphite do this for me, and save the first roundtrip, as the communication and pre-processing are costly (taking more than half the time of the entire process)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a separate line for each group you could use the groupByNode function.

```
groupByNode(group.*.item.*, 1, "sumSeries")
```

Where '1' is the node you're selecting (indexed by 0) and "sumSeries" is the function you are feeding each group into.

You can read more about this here:  http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode

If you want to restrict the second node to only numeric values you can use a character range. You do this by specifying the range in square brackets [...]. A character range is indicated by 2 characters separated by a dash (-).

```
group.[0-9].item.*
```

You can read more about this here:
http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html#paths-and-wildcards